# OpenCV counting cameras

Tags: c#, opencv, camera, emgucv

I am currently building an application which is able to access a number of USB webcams. I am well aware that there is no method which can count the number of camera devices on a machine, however, whenever I try to access a camera with a wrong index, I get a black image. Is there some way to use this image to denote a limit?

For example, I have two webcams. The application retrieves frames from the first camera at index 0, and from the second camera at index 1. When i increment index to 2, all I get is a black screen (obviously, since there is no 3rd camera attached).

So far the only way how to go about this is to access every single pixel in a 320x240 bitmap and check that it is black. This is not very efficient so maybe there's some other way of doing this which I am overlooking.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is method can count cameras.

you have to use directshow or directshow.net.

IEnumMoniker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What about non-windows platform users ?

Comment: @bubble take a look at my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be going with [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/), which has a class called [`ofVideoGrabber`](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoGrabber.html). With its `listDevices()` method you can list all available cams and choose the one you want to use.

Next thing you need: [`ofxCv`](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) is an alternative OpenCV wrapper for openFrameworks, which you can use to transfer the images grabbed by `ofVideoGrabber` to OpenCV or for the rest of the processing.

So you could do something like this:

```
// Inside Foo.h
#include "ofxCv.h"

// import namespaces for OpenCV & ofxCv
using namespace cv;
using namespace ofxCv;

// vars we need
ofVideoGrabber vidGrabber;  
ofImage inputImg; 
Mat matImg;

// setup video grabber
vidGrabber.setVerbose(true);
vidGrabber.setDeviceID(1); // choose the right one via vidGrabber.listDevices()
vidGrabber.initGrabber(320,240,false);
int grabW = vidGrabber.width;
int grabH = vidGrabber.height

// grab current frame
vidGrabber.grabFrame();
inputImg.setFromPixels(vidGrabber.getPixels(), 320, 240, OF_IMAGE_COLOR);

// get cv::Mat
matImg = toCv(inputImg).clone();

... further processing ...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there anything written in C#? I'm using EmguCV rather than OpenCv.

Comment: @swift1691 I' affraid the answer is NO, but I'm not writing any applications in C# … Btw: Your title is missleading!